# How to assign a specific service to a specific provider based on location

Tags: plugins, php, functions, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I’m looking for a way to assign a specific service to a specific provider based on location. I’m currently developing a website with various service providers providing the same service.
Do we have a way to achieve this using woocommerce?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what we have to go on, it sounds as though your locations will become WooCommerce product categories (or tags). You can also create new categories if you're already using WooCommerce's default category.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer. I want the location  to be automatically assigned

Comment: How do you mean Omar? The data has to be somewhere in order for it to be assigned to a product?? Perhaps if you could provide some more details of your requirements I can help you further.

Comment: Let’s say that you are a person who wants someone to clean his house. You logon onto my website and you choose house cleaning service, I want a system that’s choose the closest service provider to your location automatically, and send the request to them. I hope it’s clear. Thank you so much

Comment: Oh ok, so you want to use probably the Google maps API which can fetch the approximate location of the user. In WooCommerce, I'd recommend installing the ACF plugin, to add to your products a map field. From there you can set the location of your service to give it a reference point. This gets into the realms that I can't help with but from here you want to use the Google Maps API to get the users location and reference that to your services by their saved location.

Comment: Thank you Ben! That’s exactly what I want